# different Models with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, devise, multiple-users

Is it possible to generate different models with devise and have different signup forms each?

I need to have 2types of user who can both login, signup etc, but they accept different parameters.

I tried to create different models, but into my views still give me only one folder with a unique signup form. I also tried to put into this form all the parameters I have for both type users, but it returns

```
  undefined method `philosophy' for #<User:0x007fbab0961ca8>
```

where philosophy is the parameter of my second user.

I would need this to work because I'm trying to associate this 2 users one to another through active record

```
   user belongs_to :charity

   charity has_many :users
```

Any idea how I can solve this?

Comment: This really smells like you're asking the wrong question. Why do your two types of users have different parameters? What are you actually trying to accomplish? Don't explain it in terms of wanting to set up a user to user relationship -- just explain what your program aims to achieve in plain terms.

Comment: it's an e-commerce website for travelers who have lot of stuff to get rid of, before going back home, and they want to sell it. Although whatever they can't sell because there's not time left (the user gives a deadline based on the date of their departure), goes to a charity organization of their choice (organizations that are subscribe to the website) . The organization can get in contact with these people going through their profile and  maybe organize a chat session between them so they can organize a pick up date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To generate multiple models (say, User and Admin), just use:

```
> rails generate devise User
> rails generate devise Admin
```

To generate different sets of views:

Set `config.scoped_views = true` inside the `config/initializers/devise.rb` file.
You can now have views based on the role like
`users/sessions/new` and `admins/sessions/new`. If no view is found within
the scope, Devise will use the default view at devise/sessions/new.
You can use the generator to generate scoped views:

```
$ rails generate devise:views users
$ rails generate devise:views admins
```

Source: [devise github readme](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)

Comment: thank you so much.. I don't know why I didn't think of it sooner!!!! I didn't run the code for the views the second time...

Comment: If the answer helped you, please upvote/accept it. Thanks.